# How to add custom label or texts in featured image

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-thumbnails

I have tried to add custom title or hint text inside the featured image box in Worpress custom taxonomy. but didn't get the solution. how to add a custom text underneath of the **Click the image to edit or update** in featured image.

Please check the screenshot for better understanding.

https://www.screencast.com/t/VafpoWvxw

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling a javascript file for admin.

Create a javascript file in js folder in you current theme called admin.js.
inside the file add this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#postimagediv .inside').prepend('<p>Recommended image size 300*300px</p>');
});
```

Now in functions.php in your current theme folder add this code to call the javascript file exclusive for admin backend.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'custom_admin_js');
function custom_admin_js() {
    wp_register_script( 'admin-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-js' );
}
```

For different taxonomy blocks/sections you can use their identifier and in html their ID will end with div. For example if the taxonomy identifier is "some_taxonomy_identifier" the html ID will be "some_taxonomy_identifierdiv". so in js will be like this:

```
$('#some_taxonomy_identifierdiv .inside').prepend('<p>Some recommended text</p>');
```

Comment: Hi mysticalghoul,

Thank you for your information. it's working good.

Comment: but one question is how to show this type of text in different taxonomies. because i have more than one taxonomy and we need to set different hint messages like this.
now the above code is showing in  all taxonomies.
I mean , each taxonomy have different featured image size. its possible? if yes, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: @abu Check the updated answer.